# Python - Pygame: "Co-ordinates of square on sinus"

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I have problem with this code, cause I want 4 points, (which are circles) to make vertex of square, but I don't know what the difference should be between those vertexes (variable "change"). I left this variable empty, please, can you give me value I should insert there and explain why?

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from math import sin, cos

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GRAY = (175,175,175)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

angle = 0
angle_c = 0
ex = False

a = (0,0)
b = (0,0)
c = (0,0)
d = (0,0)

change = 

size = 95

x_c = 400
y_c = 200

while not ex:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             ex = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                angle_c = 0.05
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                angle_c = -0.05
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                angle_c = 0

    angle += angle_c

    a = (round(sin(angle)*size+x_c), round(cos(angle)*size+y_c))
    b = (round(sin(angle+change)*size+x_c), round(cos(angle+change)*size+y_c))
    c = (round(sin(angle+change*2)*size+x_c), round(cos(angle+change*2)*size+y_c))
    d = (round(sin(angle+change*3)*size+x_c), round(cos(angle+change*3)*size+y_c))

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (400,200), round(sin(360)*100), 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, a, 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, a, 8)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, b, 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, b, 8)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, c, 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, c, 8)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, d, 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, d, 8)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(50)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Specifically, show your best attempt and the incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

The angles from the center of a square to the square's vertices differ by 90 degrees, or `pi / 2` radians (which is the unit expected by Python's `sin` and `cos` functions).

So you *could* set your `change` variable to could be `pi / 2` (after adding `pi` to the list of names to import from the `math` module), and your code would probably work.

But it's even easier to calculate the coordinates than that, as rotations by 90 degrees change sine and cosine values in a predictable way:

- `sin(a + pi/2)` is `cos(a)`
- `cos(a + pi/2)` is `-sin(a)`.

Applying this transformation repeatedly lets you figure out what the sines and cosines should be after further rotations.

You only need to call `sin` and `cos` once each and then you can use the values to find all the coordinates.

```
y = round(sin(angle) * size)
x = round(cos(angle) * size)

a = ( x + x_c,  y + y_c)
b = (-y + x_c,  x + y_c)
c = (-x + x_c, -y + y_c)
d = ( y + x_c, -x + y_c)
```

Note that in the code above I'm following the mathematical convention that angles start at zero along the positive `x`-axis and increase as you initially start rotating towards the positive `y`-axis (which will be clockwise in pygame's coordinate system). Your previous code seemed to measure angles from the positive `y`-axis and increase in the opposite direction. If that's what you really want, you can simply reverse `x` and `y` in the initial assignments (assign the cosine to `y` and the sine to `x`).

Comment: Thank you so much. Althought I'm not sure if I understand everything, but I understand the main ;). Thanks again